# question about syntax for structure in linked list

Tags: c, struct, linked-list

I have question about the syntax for a structure inside a chained list:

I have this chain list structure:

```
typedef struct      s_list
{
    void            *content;
    size_t          content_size;
    struct s_list   *next;
} t_list;
```

I want to point void *content to this structure:

```
typedef struct      s_minos
{
    char            **minos;
}                   t_minos;
```

but when I try to acces my char **minos like this:

```
printf("%s\n", head->content->singleminos->minos[i]);
```

I declared : `s_minos *singleminos;`
and I assigned : `head->content = singleminos;`

It doesnt work.

How should I acces my data properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change this

```
printf("%s\n", head->content->singleminos->minos[i]);
```

to

```
printf("%s\n", ((t_minos *)(head->content))->minos[i]);
```

or

```
t_minos * temp = head->content;
printf("%s\n", temp->minos[i]);
```

you need to cast the `void pointer` to original type before de-referencing.